# Is One Time Pad something like this?

Tags: one-time-pad

Alphabet: [A-Z] = [0-25]

Plaintext = HELLO = 7 4 11 11 14

// QUESTION: **do this key must be as long as plaintext?**

KEY: [QWERT]
KEY = 16 23 4 17 19

Plaintext + Key = 23 27 15 28 33

Plaintext + Key (mod 26) = 23 1 15 2 7

Cyphertext: XBPCH

So is it correct that IF plaintext = "HELLO!" THEN the key must be six characters long, such as "QWERTY"?

Comment: I have no idea what you are even asking.

Comment: If the key must be as longer as the message, the plain text and the key must be equal in size (bytes). right?

Comment: @HerculesRockefeller Yes, whatever base you are using, the key should consist of as many *fully random* elements (of the same base) as the plaintext. So if you define that each ASCII character is encoded as one octet / byte, the key should have the same size in bytes. Note that you *can* encode ASCII in 7 bits, so you can save some key space if you really wanted to. Of course, it would be tricky to perform XOR if you use base 3 :) . I don't have a clue what you mean with "not xor" above, nor doesn't the key seem random. And it should be the same size, not larger.

Comment: @HerculesRockefeller please update your question to be more clear what you are really asking.

Comment: @owlstead with "not xor" I meant it was an example. thanks for all answers, my english stinks.

Comment: @HerculesRockefeller don't worry about the English. That is something we can figure out by asking questions. If you edit your question with some of the information you posted in your comments here, I will take it off of "hold". Also, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the one time pad, your key must be

1. The same length as the message. Whatever your unit of measurement (bits, bytes, etc), they must be the same length.
2. The key must be perfectly random.
3. The key is only ever used once.

Comment: This is my best attempt at what I think you are asking.

Comment: Also, the operation to combine the keys is typically bitwise-XOR, but can also be addition modulo values greater than two (also other types of invertible functions, though I'm not sure the specific requirements).

Comment: @StephenTouset I am not sure that OTP allows for such a flexibility without loosing its main security feature, ie perfect secrecy.

Comment: XOR is just modular bitwise addition. Modular addition over entire bytes (or words, or any length) is also perfectly acceptable as it is invertible, every unique key maps a plaintext to a unique ciphertext, and every possible ciphertext can be the encryption of any plaintext with a key in the same keyspace.

Comment: @StephenTouset I agree with the modular addition. My concern was about the 'other types of invertible function'.